# Go: Print text after the suite has run?

Tags: go, testing

The testing package captures all output and will not print it unless a test fails or verbose (`-v`) is turned on. Is there a way to output text *after* the suite is finished without needing verbose turned on?

For example:

```
func TestMain(m *testing.M) {
    status := m.Run(m)
    fmt.Println("important line to output")
    os.Exit(status)
}
```

Will not print the line.

---

Edit: I have found out that `fmt.Println` will work if you run the tests from inside the package (`go test`), but not if one or more packages are specified (`go test ./...`) unless the `-v` option is enabled.

Comment: Are you asking how to get the output after the test has passed but when it was run without the `-v` flag been set?

Comment: No, I want to output some text after all tests have finished without needing the `-v` flag.

Comment: The output inside the tests is normally not send to Stdout, just in case of an error. This is important, because if you would run your tests of a huge project in verbose mode you would have a lot of unimportant output of the passed tests.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> The testing package captures all output and will not print it unless a
>   test fails or verbose (-v) is turned on

What makes you say that stdout is captured? If I save this code into `main_test.go` and run `go test`:

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "os"
    "testing"
)

func TestJoe(t *testing.T) {
    fmt.Println("from joe")
}

func TestMain(m *testing.M) {
    fmt.Println("before run")
    s := m.Run()
    fmt.Println("after run")
    os.Exit(s)
}
```

I get:

```
$ go test
before run
from joe
PASS
after run
```

---

About output with `./...`, here's an excerpt from `go help test`:

> The second, called package list mode, occurs when go test is invoked
>   with explicit package arguments (for example 'go test math', 'go test
>   ./...', and even 'go test .'). In this mode, go test compiles and
>   tests each of the packages listed on the command line. If a package
>   test passes, go test prints only the final 'ok' summary line. If a
>   package test fails, go test prints the full test output. If invoked
>   with the -bench or -v flag, go test prints the full output even for
>   passing package tests, in order to display the requested benchmark
>   results or verbose logging.

Comment: I have found one issue. If you run the tests from within the package it will output (`go test`), but not if you run the tests from outside (`go test ./mypackage`). I commonly use `go test ./...` and nothing is printed unless `-v` is enabled but then I get tons of other verbose output I don't want.

Comment: @ElliotChance: I see. I added an excerpt from `go help test` to my answer, PTAL